# How can I prevent Swiper from showing `^` in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

After installing ivy layer. Press `M-x` will display "^" in spacemacs, how can I remove it?

[image: the ^ in ivy]

Comment: I guess you are talking about https://oremacs.com/swiper/#ivy, not [tag:ivy] the Java build tool. I have removed the misleading tag.

Comment: This number is the number of results. I'm on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behavior -- the input you are asked for is a regular expression, and the carret `^` is the beginning-of-string anchor.  You can modify this by setting up `ivy-initial-inputs-alist` to your wishes via e.g. `M-x customize-variable`.